# Deploy a django project on Heroku (Windows) :

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm trying to deploy a Django app from the first time using Heroku. But my app is always returning an application error.

When I check `heroku logs --tail` I get:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/app/CandiBot/logs/08/16.log'
```

The tree structure of my project looks like this, I think I missed a folder called `myproject/` but I guess the issue is not related to that.

```
CandiEnv/ (venv)
├── Candiapp/ (app)
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── views.py
│   ├── ...
│   ├── static/
│   │    └──(empty)
│   └── logs/
│        └── 08/16.log  <-- Here is the log file
├── myproject/ (I don't know why I've named it differently)
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├──...
├── manage.py
└── Procfile
```

Maybe it has to do with my `settings.py`. The static part looks like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
BASE_DIR= os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( #Not sure it's useful
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
    )
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your static files.

It looks like you're trying to log to a file. That won't work on Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem): your logs will be lost whenever your dyno restarts. This [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#automatic-dyno-restarts) (at least once per day).

Instead, [simply write to `stdout` or `stderr`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#writing-to-your-log). Heroku's logger will collect that output and merge it with logs from other sources. On Django that means [setting up a `StreamHandler`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/logging/#examples) instead of a `FileHandler`.

Note that [Heroku doesn't keep logs very long](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging#log-history-limits). Given that you were trying to write to a file named after the current date I suspect that you might want to hang onto more than the most recent 1,500 messages / last seven days of messages. In that case, [a logging addon](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#logging) is the simplest solution and [a log drain](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/log-drains) is the most powerful.

Answer (score 0):

Git does not handle empty folder well.

Try deleting the empty folder at `CandiEnv/Candispo/static/` and `08/16.log`. Even though this has a file extension I am guessing it is a folder with a `.` in the name.